# Equally distribute fixed width divs in a grid

Tags: html, css

I am stuck in a weird situation. I am trying to build a grid system where all the elements have the same fixed width (200px to be specific). I want to build a smart grid system using only CSS where each "row" will try to fit as many content as it can to the first one and take the number of columns in the first one and use it in all the other "rows".

For example: Let's say I have a container of width 640px. The grid will try to fit as many as it can in the first line and justify to have an equally distributed line. As a result, the first line will have 3 elements of size 200px with 20px between each (assume there is no padding). Now, the grid will use 20px margin for the rest of the lines.

I can't seem to find a CSS solution to work with this. My current implementation, which doesn't work, is as follows:

```
.grid {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   text-align: justify;
}

.grid::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid .item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

This implementation has one major problem. Each line MUST have the same number of elements. So, if line 1 has 3 elements, line 2 must have 3 elements, otherwise line 2 wouldn't justify at all. Since this didn't work, I tried to give container a width of 95% and added `margin: 0 auto;`. This didn't work because I calculate the margin between elements. This is the moment I wish flex box was supported. I don't build websites that support IE8 but if IE9 doesn't support a spec, I can't use it. I know I can achieve this with JS but I want to know if I can achieve it with CSS.

My current guess on solving my problem is calculating a margin-left/right based on the width of the elements. I don't want this grid system to be the ultimate flexible grid system that works on any width. All I want it to do is to show one element per row on phones, 3 elements per row on laptops, and 5 elements per row on larger displays.

Sorry for a long post.

TL;DR I need to built a grid system that distributes the first line based on the given width of the container and uses the margins of the first line on the Nth line.

Comment: You can learn [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries and create scenarios:

2 items-wrap  per row
3 items-wrap per row
.. and so on.

At this point you'd just need to add clear right to `nth-child(n)`selector;

Clearly this needs to be done not on the item itself but on a item-wrapper that takes care of the margins for you;

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid {
  align-content: space-around;
  background: gold;
  max-width: 640px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.grid .item {
  background: lightseagreen;
  padding: 24px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

It seems to work, but it's hard to control the vertical spacing as it will of course depend on the `height` of your container, but you could use percentage or fixed margin on the y-axis.